# Is there any way to install Ubuntu12.04 on HP Gen9 server?

Tags: 12.04

HP Gen9 server doesn't support Ubuntu12.04, it just support Ubuntu14.04, but I have needs to install Ubuntu12.04 on it. During the installation, I met raid driver issue, is there any workaround to make it happen? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 12.04.5 has same kernel 3.13 as Ubuntu 14.04.

I see no reason why 12.04.5 can not be installed, if 14.04 can.

But I see no reason why not install 14.04 as well.

Comment: Thank for reply! Maybe I confused you, the Ubuntu12.04 kernel I have is 3.2.0-23-generic. Any idea?

Comment: Now Ubuntu version 12.04.5 is available for downloading. http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/. It has 3.13 kernel. @nfan3

Comment: @nfan3 If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.